# The xlabel and ylabel are not shown when I run this this code

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I use this code to plot a diagram I get the plot but the x and y label are not shown.

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history["loss"], "b", label="Mean Square Error of training")
plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"], "g", label="Mean Square Error of validation")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Epoche")
plt.ylabel("Mean Square Error")
plt.xlim(0,200)
plt.show()
plt.savefig(r"C:\Users\aheidari\Dropbox\Dissertation\primary hot water use prediction\Diagrams\UnivariateTrainingerror.png", dpi=1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just have to remove the history. before history:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

history = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['loss','val_loss'])

plt.plot(history["loss"], "b", label="Mean Square Error of training")
plt.plot(history["val_loss"], "g", label="Mean Square Error of validation")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Epoche")
plt.ylabel("Mean Square Error")
plt.show()
```